# onmousedown doesn't callback after changing class dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following divs:

```
<div class="celula" id="838">                       
</div>
<div class="celula" id="839">                       
</div>
<div class="celula" id="840">                       
</div>
```

I change them dynamically using jquery with an ajax response so far it works great.
Imagine that it generates the following:

```
<div class="checked" id="838">                      
</div>
<div class="checked" id="839">                      
</div>
<div class="checked" id="840">                      
</div>
```

Complete js callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("templatenome").innerHTML = screen.width + " - " + screen.height;


    $('.celula').on('mousedown', function(){

         var template = $("#templatenome").attr("name");
         var $div = document.getElementById (this.id);
            $div.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../resources/"+template+"/images/CelulaPOP.png')";

              var audio = document.getElementById("audio");
              audio.play();

              $(document).one('mouseup', function(){
                  sendAjax($div.id);
                $div.style.backgroundImage = "url('../../resources/"+template+"/images/CelulaSEL.png')";
            });

    });

    $(document).on('mousedown', '.checked', function(){
          $(document).one('mouseup', function(){
          });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a delegated event handler, attached to a non-changing ancestor of the dynamic elements:

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.checked', function(){
      $(document).one('mouseup', function(){
           alert("I was mouse-uppped on a .checked div!");
      });

});
```

As you do not want the previous handler to operate once the class is changed (see comments below), make that a delegated handler too:

e.g.

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.celula', function(){
```

This applies the jQuery selector at *event time* only, so the elements only need to match then (and not when the event was registered).

`document` is the best default if nothing closer is available/convenient. Do not use `'body'` as it has a bug (if styling results in a calculated body height of 0 it will not bubble mouse events to `body`)

Here is a little demo showing how events will fire with the delegated event handlers as the classes are changed:

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/5xb6vohp/3/

Comment: It doesn't have any effect... I forgot to mention its in a document.ready function

Comment: @Kunal: where it is is irrelevant (your code can be inside a DOM ready handler). It *will* work. You need to show how you are trying it :)

Comment: @Kunal: Thanks. I have added a simple test JSFiddle to demostrate what this does.

Comment: @Kunal: You have no code inside your new `mousedown`/`one mouseup` handler... what do you expect it to do? :) Also your DIVs are currently empty, so you have nothing to click on. What does your styling look like?

Comment: i saw your JSFiddle but it puts a concole log for both checked and celula classes. I just needed for checked. the class for celula was replaced by checked since i didn't want to do anything with it anymore

Comment: Then make the other handler delegated as well. I will update the example.

Comment: @Kunal: Example updated to allow you to test what I meant. Both handlers  are not delegated, so will appear to toggle on/off based on the class.

Comment: Thats exactly what i needed! I will try to implement it in my code and then i will accept your answer. Thank You very much :)